# How to establish a remote desktop connection to an iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios5, remote-desktop

Actually i am developing stuff for the iPad, but fiddling with Firebug lite is no fun and is limited.

I would like to remotely control an iPad from my pc or mac - if possible without jail break.
Something like "windows desktop remote connection" to remotly control another OS - but for the iPad.

**How can i achieve that?**

Update: Why do i get downvotes here? Please clarify!

Comment: will this work, www.ipadpeek.com

Comment: Why would you want to test with a mouse? Touch and mouse input is very different and would probably end with a poor user experience.

Comment: What sort of "control" are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: a function like "windows desktop remote" to remotly control another OS

Comment: @refhat: no, this is not what i want - i want to see my iPad desktop on another device - no iPad simulator!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know I don't think there is anything available yet. But I just saw a forum with some info about this topic:

http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1488754

**UPDATE**

I think you need [this](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/shadow/)

[Chrome Extension is Also available](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ijoeapleklopieoejahbpdnhkjjgddem/)